# Change Tab programatically in TabView Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml

How do I change tabs in TabView in Qt Quick QML
here is my code

```
TabView {
        id: main_tab
        width: 799
        height: 560
        tabsVisible: false

        Tab {
            id: home_tab
            source: "Home.qml"
            title: "Home"
        }
        Tab {
            id: led_tab
            source: "Led.qml"
            title: "Led"
        }
}
```

I tried to set new tab using `main_tab.getTab(1).active = true` but it was not a success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the [`currentIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html#currentIndex-prop) property of your [`TabView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html) :

```
main_tab.currentIndex = 0 // Will show home_tab
main_tab.currentIndex = 1 // Will show led_tab
```